# How can we make exact index as case insensitive in springdata neo4j

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

with neo4j core API we can create an exact index and also make it as case_insensitive like below Here’s an example of how to create an exact index which is case-insensitive:

```
Index index = graphDb.index().forNodes( "exact-case-insensitive", stringMap( "type", "exact", "to_lower_case", "true" ) ); 
Node node = graphDb.createNode(); index.add( node, "name", "Thomas Anderson" );
assertContains( index.query( "name", "\"Thomas Anderson\"" ), node ); 
assertContains( index.query( "name", "\"thoMas ANDerson\"" ), node );
```

i know fulltext does this by default in springdata neo4j. but i want to make my exact index as case insensitive in springdata neo4j.

but i didn't find any attribute for `@indexed()` to make an exact index as case_insensitive. so please help me to do this if any mechanism is there..

thank you,,